# Angular10 File Upload to django Server

Tags: django, angular10

I'm trying to upload a CSV file using Angular HTTP Client. But when i check the `request.FILES` in backend it shows `<MultiValueDict: {}>`. Apparently the file data is coming in `request.body` as byte string. Below is sample angular code for you reference.

```
const upload_url = `${BASE_URL}/data-upload`;

// Create form data instance
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('data_file', file, file.name);

// Update header
const headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}

this.http.post(upload_url, formData, {headers: headers}).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

How can i get the same file data in `request.FILES`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! File upload infers Content-Type Header while uploading the data to the server.
I have removed the header from the above code and uploaded the file and it worked perfectly.

Here's the response after uploading the file from `request.FILES`: `<MultiValueDict: {'data_file': [<TemporaryUploadedFile: dummy-data.csv (application/vnd.ms-excel)>]}>`